# After IIS recycles, global.asax is not called

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have set up my IIS application pool to have a maximum of 5 worker processes, and the application pool will recycle the worker processes every 29 hours.

After it recycles the worker process, the old worker process dies and a new worker process is created. Is it possible for the constructor in the global.asax.cs to get called automatically after a new worker process is created?

Since there are a maximum of 5 worker processes, I want all 5 worker processes to call their global.asax.cs constructor after it is recycled.

I have been able to get the constructor of the global.asax.cs to be called when I manually go to the URL in a browser, but was wondering if there was another solution or a IIS property that I have to set

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2013/03/05/speeding-up-your-application-with-the-iis-auto-start-feature/

Comment: thanks, that link worked great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zimaden provided a pretty useful link

There is also this, I came across It and it *touches* on System.Web.HttpApplication. "life cycle"

[how many times is System.Web.HttpApplication is initialised per process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572154/how-many-times-is-system-web-httpapplication-is-initialised-per-process)